# If $F_1 \cup F_2 = \mathbb{R}$ and $F_1,F_2$ are closed sets then $\mbox{Int}F_1 \neq \emptyset$ or $\mbox{Int}F_2 \neq \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

Prove that if $F_1 \cup F_2 = \mathbb{R}$ and $F_1,F_2$ are closed sets (in euclidean space) then $\mbox{Int}F_1 \neq \emptyset$ or $\mbox{Int}F_2 \neq \emptyset$

My idea is prove that by contradiction. So let suppose that $\mbox{Int}F_1 = \emptyset$ and $\mbox{Int}F_2 = \emptyset$. So $F_1,F_2$ are border sets. And what can I do next? I can't gain contradiction. I will grateful for yuor hints.

Comment: This follows since $\mathbb R$ is a Baire space. Not sure if you want to use that.

Comment: So we have that exsists $k \in \left\{ 1,2\right\} $ such that $\mbox{Int}(\mbox{Cl}F_k) \neq \emptyset$. Because $F_k$ are closed so we have thesis.

Answer (score 1):

This is Baire' Theorem for complete spaces.

Here let's suppose that $ Int F_1,IntF_2=\emptyset$. Then $\Bbb R- Int F_1=\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R- Int F_2=\Bbb R$.

We have that $\Bbb R- Int F_1$=Cl$ (\Bbb R-  F_1)$ and $\Bbb R- Int F_2$=Cl$ (\Bbb R-  F_2)$.

Thus Cl$ (\Bbb R-  F_1)=\Bbb R$ and Cl$ (\Bbb R-  F_2)=\Bbb R$ $=>$ $G_1=(\Bbb R-  F_1)$ and $G_2=(\Bbb R-  F_2)$ are dense in $\Bbb R$. Moreover every $G_{i}$ is open in $\Bbb R$.

From Baire's Theorem we have that $G_1\cap G_2 \neq \emptyset=> F_1^{c}\cap F_2^{c} \neq \emptyset => (F_1\cup F_2 )^{c}\neq \emptyset=>\Bbb R ^{c}\neq \emptyset=>\emptyset \neq \emptyset$

Comment: Could you tell me why $\Bbb R - IntF_1 = Cl( \Bbb R - F_1)$

Comment: Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subset X$. Then $X-Cl(A)=Int(X-A)$. We will show that $Cl(A)\cap Int(X-A)=\emptyset$ and $X=Cl(A)\cup Int(X-A)$. Let $x\in X$. Then only one of the two propositions is true. "for every $ε>0 B(x,ε)\cap A \neq \emptyset$"(1)  or " there is a $ε>0:B(x,ε) \cap A =\emptyset$"(2). The (1) means that $x\in Cl(A)$ and the (2)means that $x\in Int(X-A)$. Now, in the relation $X-Cl(A)=Int(X-A)$ if we put $X-A$ in the position of $A$ we have that $X-IntA=Cl(X-A)$

Comment: Let $X$ be a topological space and $A\subset X$. Then $X-Cl(A)=Int(X-A)$. We will show that $Cl(A)\cap Int(X-A)=\emptyset$ and $X=Cl(A)\cup Int(X-A)$. Let $x\in X$. Then only one of the two propositions is true. "for every $ε>0$ $B(x,ε)\cap A \neq \emptyset$ "(1) or " there is a $ε>0$:$B(x,ε) \cap A =\emptyset$ (2). The (1) means that $x\in Cl(A)$ and the (2)means that $x\in Int(X-A)$.  Now, in the relation $X-Cl(A)=Int(X-A)$  if we put $X-A$ in the position of $A$ we have that $X-IntA=Cl(X-A)$.

Comment: @Thomas ,check my proof please.thank you